# How do you reconcile Apollo cache for two queries on the same object that return different subsets of data?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

For example, let's say I have a query A for some Resource:1

```
Resource {
 id
 info
}
```

and another query B for the same Resource:1

```
 Resource {
  id
  info
  additionalInfo
 }
```

In most cases this isn't an issue, but it seems like the order of these queries matters. If A runs, then B runs, then A runs again, an optimistic response from a Mutation interleaved with these Queries may crash, citing that additionalInfo is missing from the current state of Resource:1 in the cache. I assume this is from the results of Query A overwriting the results of Query B in the cache.

In the case of a Mutation, I would just use the update callback to reconcile the cache manually between each of these calls, but is there an equivalent operation for Queries?

Comment: The expected behavior is for those results to be merged together. It sounds like the optimistic result is the problem, not the queries themselves. Can you update your question with the relevant code?